# Reference list and Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I am currently writing a paper and need to include both

- a reference list {with items i have cited throughout my text}, and
- a bibliography {with items i made reference too whilst doing the thesis and are not cited in the text}

I am using a bibtex file to keep all references in order.

I have managed to get a reference list by making use of

```
\cite{Ccone}
\cite{3rings}
...
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{ref1}
```

where ref1 is the .bib file containing all my references.

I have tried the `\nocite{*}` command to include the bibliography. However, this overwrites the whole reference list and everything is included in the same list. This is the code I am currently using:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text
...
\cite{Ccone}
\cite{3rings}
\nocite{*}
...
%\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{ref1}
...
%\section*{Bibliography}
\bibliography{ref1}
...
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```